# Java Scanner Class useDelimiter Method

Tags: java

I have to read from a text file containing all the NCAA Division 1 championship games since 1933,

the file is in this format:   1939:Villanova:42:Brown:30
                         1945:New York University:70:Ohio State:65 **The fact that some Universities have multiple white spaces is giving me lots of trouble beause we are only to read the school names and discard the year, points and colon. I do not know if I have to use a delimiter that discards what spaces, but buttom line is I am a very lost.

We are to discard the date, points, and ":".  I am slightly fimilar with the useDelimiter method but, I have read that a .split("") might be useful.  I am having a great deal of problems due to my lack of knowledge in patterns.

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

```
class NCAATeamTester
{
public static void main(String[]args)throws IOException
{
NCAATeamList myList = new NCAATeamList();     //ArrayList containing teams
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("ncaa2012.data"));   
in.useDelimiter("[A-Za-z]+");      //String Delimeter excluding non alphabetic chars or ints
while(in.hasNextLine()){
String line = in.nextLine();
String name = in.next(line); 
String losingTeam = in.next(line);
//Creating team object with winning team 
NCAATeamStats win = new NCAATeamStats(name); 
myList.addToList(win);       //Adds to List
//Creating team object with losing team 
NCAATeamStats lose = new NCAATeamStats(losingTeam);
myList.addToList(lose)
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have one year per line? If so, a simple solution would be to use newline as a delimiter, split the lines using ":" and keep the second and fourth elements in the array.

Comment: If you necessarily want to use a scanner, you should be using the colon as delimiter (`in.useDelimiter(":");`). Otherwise I agree with the people who answered below, that it probably simpler to just use String.split.

Comment: I'm wondering if you would want to look into using regular expressions. [Check this is for php but the concepts remain the same.](http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=33147)

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
String[] spl = line.split(':');
String name1 = spl[1]; 
String name2 = spl[3];
```

?

Or, if there are more records at the same line, use regular expressions :

```
String line = "1939:Villanova:42:Brown:30   1945:New York University:70:Ohio State:65";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?:){4}[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

while (m.find())
{
    String[] spl = m.group().split(':');
    String name = spl[1];
    String name2 = spl[3];
}
```